# Golang: function return argument error

Tags: go

The following code gives:

```
runtime.main: call to external function main.main
runtime.main: main.main: not defined
runtime.main: undefined: main.main
```

I messed up with the return argument, but why?

Requesting:

```
fmt.Println( reflect.TypeOf(l))
```

gives *ldap.Conn as type

The code works without trying to return the object

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/ldap.v2"
)


var Ldap1 = "10.0.0.1"
var Lport1 = 389
var Prpl1 = "cn=admin,dc=Example,dc=com"
var Pass1 = "password"

func Bindldap(ldaphost string, port int, principal string, password string) *ldap.Conn {

    l, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", ldaphost, port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()

    err = l.Bind(principal, password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return l
}

func Main() {
    a := Bindldap(Ldap1, Lport1, Prpl1, Pass1)
    //do something with a
}
```

Comment: It's looking for `main.main`.  You have `main.Main`.

Comment: ohh...man.... sorry to have wasted your time

Comment: No problem, this is what SO is for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error messages are telling you it's looking for a function called `main` in your `main` package.  You called your entry point `Main` (Note the caps).  Try this:

```
func main() {
    a := Bindldap(Ldap1, Lport1, Prpl1, Pass1)
    //do something with a
}
```